# how to check messages from kafka topics with host,server name and brokers list

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka topics, server name,port, and also brokers list.

How can i see the data from consumer with these details..

Comment: By the way https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Try running this from your kafka directory:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <BROKER_IP>:<PORT> --topic <TOPIC_NAME> --from-beginning
```

It's the quickest way to test consuming from a topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot but am not able to veiw the data from those topics...as the data is being sent by the data providers and we have to consume the data and place in hdfs and store in hive tables.

Comment: @sonia Please edit your question to include this command's output. Plus, you said nothing about HDFS in your question